# Java class without main method from a C++ progamer

Tags: java

I am new to Java programming. But I am reading other people's Java codes, and it seems all Java classes have a main() method. In C++, we can define different classes , e.g. class A, class B, class C, and there is no main method in these classes, we have another main program that defines the objects of these classes and use them. Is this possible in Java? Can I define some classes, without main() method inside them, and then I have another class that calls other classes? Thank you.

Comment: Yes you can. There only has to be a `main` method in one class.

Comment: No, not ALL java classes have to have a `main` method. Just like C/C++, there typically is a single entry point into the application which is detonated by a `public static void main(String[])` method. Java allows for more then one class to define a `main` method and you can execute these separately from the command line, but typically, you'd define a "single" "common" (class) entry point for your app.  From there, your classes can start calling each other as they please

Comment: In fact, you could have a project/library which has no `main` method.  This would then be called from another project/library which eventually link all the way back to a single `main` method

Comment: You can have as much `main` as you want. You can even have no at all, for example in an API that is not intended to be started. You need a `main` method as soon as you want to start a program. So if you say Java should start a program you need to tell it a place where it can find a `main` method, like in C. The down-votes on your question are due to lack of research, also see the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html) by Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

Java's `public static void main(String args[])` method only belongs in the main class. This is the class where the program starts executing at the main method. From this method, you can create new objects and call other methods in other classes. A main method is where the program enters, so each time a program is run, only one main method can be executed. So yes, you can call other classes from the main method and other methods, just like in C++.

Comment: That's not _quite_ true. You can have as many classes with `main` methods of you want, and many projects do in fact have different entry points, it's just that only one is ever used at any time.

Comment: Oh, maybe I should edit that. Thanks!

Comment: You can also have a project with no `main` at all. For example an API that is not intended to be run from within itself. And there are also some exceptions, for example so called **agents** (projects that are loaded dynamically at runtime) are started with the `agentmain` method.

Comment: Yeah, it would eventually get imported into a program with a main method so that the methods in that program could be run.